# How to trigger allauth.account.signals.user_signed_up signal using pytest?

Tags: django, django-allauth, pytest-django

I have a `OneToOneField` between my `UserTrust` model and `django.contrib.auth.models.User` that I would like to create whenever a new `User` registers. I thought on creating the `UserTrust` instance using the `user_signed_up` signal.

I have the following code in my `AppConfig`

```
    def ready(self):
        # importing model classes
        from .models import UserTrust

        @receiver(user_signed_up)
        def create_usertrust(sender, **kwargs):
            u = kwargs['user']
            UserTrust.objects.create(user=u)
```

... and this is in my pytest test

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_password():
   return 'strong-test-pass'

  
@pytest.fixture
def create_user(db, django_user_model, test_password):
   def make_user(**kwargs):
    kwargs['password'] = test_password
    if 'username' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['username'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
    return django_user_model.objects.create_user(**kwargs)
   return make_user


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_my_user(create_user):
  user = create_user()
  assert user.usertrust.available == 1000
```

Still, the test fails with

> django.contrib.auth.models.User.usertrust.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no usertrust.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with you creating the user via the django_user_model is that it doesn't actually pass through the allauth code that actually sends that signal. You've got two options:

1. Use a `client` (since I'm assuming you're using pytest-django) and fill out a registration via the allauth provided link for registering new users. That way, a signal is sent, and you can assert attributes and model instances like that.
2. You can simply ignore the signal and unittest the function itself. That's it. You put your trust in that single registration view not changing at all and put your trust in the package that the API will not change. I can still recommend this option, but you've been warned.
3. You can send the signal yourself. Not recommended in case allauth's API changes, but you could just import the signal from allauth and send it like this: `user_signed_up.send(sender=self.__class__, toppings=toppings, size=size)` where `user_signed_up` is the signal. Ref the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#sending-signals

Again, definitely recommend the first one in case of API changes. I can also recommend the second option just because allauth is pretty reputable and you know what going to happen without too huge of an package change, but you never know.